# Flask form appends form data to url on submit

Tags: python, forms, flask, search, python-requests

I have a HTML form

```
<form>
 <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" />
<input type="submit">Submit</input>
```

on submits I want to pass form data to flask app

> requests.py

```
def search_news(keyword):
search_news_url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q={}&language=en&apiKey={}'.format(keyword,api_key)
with urllib.request.urlopen(search_news_url) as url:
    search_news_data = url.read()
    search_news_response = json.loads(search_news_data)

    search_news_results = None

    if search_news_response['articles']:
        search_news_list = search_news_response['articles']
        search_news_results = process_search_results(search_news_list)

return search_news_results

def process_search_results(search_news_list):
news_results = []
for search_results_item in search_news_list:
    author = search_results_item.get('author')
    title = search_results_item.get('title')
    description = search_results_item.get('description')
    url = search_results_item.get('url')
    urlToImage = search_results_item.get('urlToImage')
    publishedAt = search_results_item.get('publishedAt')
    content = search_results_item.get('content')
    totalResults = search_results_item.get('totalResults')

    if content:
        news_results_object = Everything(author,title,description,url,urlToImage,publishedAt,content,totalResults)
        news_results.append(news_results_object)
return news_results
```

> views.py

```
from ..requests import get_everything,search_news
....
@main.route('/')
    def index():
    everything = get_everything()
    title = 'News Highlight'
    searching_news = request.args.get('keyword')

if searching_news:
    redirect(url_for('.search',keyword = searching_news))
return render_template('index.html',title = title,everything = everything)


....
@main.route('/search/<keyword>')
def search(keyword):
keyword_list = keyword.split(" ")
keyword_format = '%20'.join(keyword_list)
searched_news = search_news(keyword_format)
title = f'Search results for {keyword} '
return render_template('search.html',searched_news = searched_news)
```

on form submits it appends form data to url like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/?keyword=game+of+thrones
```

I've tried using post methods but i get a **server does not support method error**. Can anyone help please.

but when I append link like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/search/game%20%of%thrones
```

the app searches and displays results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, form data is submitted via the URL's query string if you don't tell it to behave differently (the `method` defaults to `GET`).

#### Post

If you want to send the data to flask using a `POST` request, this is the way to go:

1. Make sure to tell your HTML form to use `method="POST"` and tell it where to send it's data via the `action` attribute:

   ```html
   <form method="post" action="/search">
      <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" />
      <input type="submit">Submit</input>
   </form>
   ```
2. Tell your server-side view to accept `POST` requests and fetch the sent data from `request.form`. In `views.py` use

   ```py
   @main.route('/search/' methods=['POST'])
   def search():
       keyword = request.form['keyword']
       ...
   ```

#### Get

If you want to use a `GET` request and pass the data via query string set your form's method to `get`

```html
<form method="get" action="/search">
   <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" />
   <input type="submit">Submit</input>
</form>
```

On submit, your browser will append the values entered in the input field to the URL as a query string: `?keyword=<whatever-you-entered>`.

Tell your server-side view to accept `GET` requests and fetch query string data  via `request.args.get()`. In `views.py` use

```py
@main.route('/search/' methods=['GET'])
def search():
    keyword = request.args.get('keyword')
    ...
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data) has got a nice article with more details around sending and retreiving form data with HTML and Python, this might be worth a read, too.

Comment: The above solutions returns a 404 error . On submit it appends only /search/ alone and leaves out the query. I wanted to make it append formatted keyword prepended by the /search

Comment: @GeoffreyMungai I've corrected the post example and added an example to handle this via a get request.

Comment: Thanks both the methods above work . But if you submit an empty form its raises a 400 bad request error. but putting a `required` like this `<input type="text" class="searchTerm" name="keyword" placeholder="What are you looking for?" required>` solves the problem